# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API: HttpContext getting null randomly. May be when API receives large number of requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, using controllers. It's deployed on Azure as a web app.

It is working fine. The problem is sometime I am receiving `HttpContext` as null, not sure but it may occurs because of large number of requests start coming (more than 1k per second).

In my `program.cs`, I have:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
..
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And in my API controller, I am using `httpContext` from dependency injection:

```
IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public MyController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

[HttpGet("MyMethod")]
public IActionResult MyMethod()
{
    var currentRequest = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request;

    if (currentRequest == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(currentRequest), "CurrentRequest received is NULL !");
    }
}
```

Ideally the `httpContext` should not be null in any case, but It throws error (although it happens rarely).

Am I missing some configuration? Or do I need to improve some code?

Comment: You don't have to go through `IHttpContextAccessor`, you can just use your controller's `HttpContext`.

Comment: _"And in my API controller, I am using httpContext from dependency injection:"_ - as @EtiennedeMartel wrote. I would use even harsher wording - not only you don't have, you should not in the shown case use  `IHttpContextAccessor` over [`ControllerBase.HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-8.0) (i.e. for example `this.HttpContext`). Also please show real code which leads to the defined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is sometime I am receiving HttpContext as null, not sure
> but it may occurs because of large number of requests start coming
> (more than 1k per second). Am I missing some configuration? Or do I
> need to improve some code?

According to your code snippet, it might be related to how ASP.NET Core handles request concurrency. When a large number of requests are being processed concurrently, there's a possibility of the `HttpContext` being null at certain points, especially if the request has already been completed or if it's at the early stages of processing. So, ensure that your `actions/methods` are marked as `asynchronous (async)`

If they are performing asynchronous operations. Sometimes, synchronous code in high-concurrency scenarios can lead to race conditions.

Therefore, yeah, you are missing async. In addition, you can directly can use context instead of using `IHttpContextAccessor`.

So you can write as following:

```
 var currentRequest = HttpContext?.Request;
```

According to Microsoft official docs, as its not thread-safe so out of process block it might result in null reference intermittently. As you can see below:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#access-httpcontext-from-a-controller) for more information.